# how to change the image as black and white when it is hovered with the blur effect

Tags: html, css

I want to change this to black and white image. Can anyone help me?

```css
BLUR*/
.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/pic-of-nature/pic-of-nature-3.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add : `-webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);`

```css
BLUR*/
.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);

}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/pic-of-nature/pic-of-nature-3.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```css
.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blur img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/pic-of-nature/pic-of-nature-3.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```css
BLUR*/
.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);

filter: grayscale(100%);

}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/pic-of-nature/pic-of-nature-3.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
BLUR*/
.blur img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.blur img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);
   filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur pic">
  <img src="http://www.spyderonlines.com/images/wallpapers/pic-of-nature/pic-of-nature-3.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: every one has give the same